# Why isn't CSS loading consistently in my printing iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, my page has a div that I want to print. It uses bootstrap and fontawesome to look good. To print it, I have a button to create an iframe, copy the outerHTML into its body and some css and js to its head, make some modifications to fit the A4 paper, print it and then remove it. The thing is that the first time I click the button it shows chrome's print page beautifully, exactly the way I want, but when I click the button again it looses some of the styling.

I noticed on the network tab of chrome's devtools that the js and css files load just fine the first time but after that it shows as pending when the printing window is shown, only loading after I close it.

This is the function called by the button:

```
function print1(elem)
{
    $('<iframe>', {
        id: 'printFrame',
        name: 'printFrame',
        class: 'printFrame',
        style: 'display: none'
    }).appendTo('body').contents()

    .find('head')
        .append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />')
        .append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">')
        .append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed">')
        .append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/wscustom.css" type="text/css">')
        .append('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" />')
        .append('<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" />')
        .append($('style')[0].outerHTML)
        .parent()

    .find('body')
        .css('font-family', 'Roboto, sans-serif')
        .css('font-size', '14px')
        .css('line-height', '1.428571429')
        .css('color', '#333')
        .css('box-sizing', 'border-box')
        .append('<div class="container">')
        .find('.container')
        .append($('#' + elem).clone())

    .find('div.col-xs-12.col-md-6.col-lg-4')
        .removeClass('col-xs-12').removeClass('col-md-6').removeClass('col-lg-4').addClass('col-4')
        .css('width', '31.7%')
        .css('margin', '5px')
        .css('height', '514px')
        .css('float', 'left')
        .css('position', 'relative')
        .find('.fa-redo').hide();

    window.frames['printFrame'].focus();
    window.frames['printFrame'].print();
    $("#printFrame").remove();
}
```

Like I mentioned above, I suspect it has something to do with the js and css files that are hanging on "pending" while the print window is open.

Besides a lot of bootstrap styling missing, one detail that shows when it works (the first time I click the button) are fontawesome stars in blue and gray. After the first click it sometimes shows in black and sometimes doesn't show at all.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably printing before everything is loaded. Put your print action in the iframe, not the parent page, and wrap it in a READY handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() { window.print(); }
```

Comment: I appended a script tag and appended to it your suggested code (because for some reason i can't just do `.append('<script>$(document).ready(function() { window.print(); }</script>')` because it gives me the `Unterminated string constant` error, I'm in Visual Studio 2012).
Anyway, it didn't work. The print window didn't appear.
Thanks for the pitch anyways! =D